# How to check whether string contains any element present in the string array

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

```
string str = "cat:fox";
string[] strArr = new string[] { "cat", "dog" };
```

I have a string like `str`. I need to check whether that string contains any element present in the `strArr` like exactly "cat" or "dog".

**If the string is "cat:fox" method should returns true.
If the string is "dog:fox" method should returns true.**

The thing I tried was:

```
string[] split = str.Split(':');
blnReturn = false;

foreach (var item in split)
{
  foreach(var item1 in strArr)
  {
    if(item == item1)
       blnReturn = true;
  }
}
```

**Note :- Meaning is values are concatenated with colon.I need to check whether that string contains any value present in the strArr.**

How to do this better?

**UPDATE**

Requirement is if str is `str = "cat dfgfg:fox";` It should not return true.
Only it should be cat.

Otherwise we can check this way `strData = str.Split(':');` 
and strArr is already there.

*Condition is any one data in strArr (string array) should match with strData (string array)
then it should return true.*

Comment: What's wrong with this code you wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to distinguish between "cat" and "cats" you better do:

```
bool Match(string str, string[] strArr)
{
    return strArr.Intersect(str.Split(':')).Any();
}
```

Comment: Rather than `.Count() > 0`, use `.Any()`. The reason is that `Count()` requires that the entire list be enumerated whereas `.Any()` will stop as soon as one is found.

Comment: @JimMischel I updated my answer. I appreciate it if people think about performance when using Linq.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string str = "cat:dog";
string[] strArr = new string[] { "cat", "dog" };

if (strArr.Any(str.Contains))
{
  // Your string contains one the array values
}
```

Of course this works also `cats`, `catss` and `cat:asdasd:dog` becuase of the `Contains` definition.

You didn't mentioned but if you don't want to match string like `cat:asdasd dog` check out [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19923987/447156) which looks the correct one.

Comment: though that would match `cats` instead of matching only `cat`

Comment: that has edge-cases, though; should `"cat:prairie dog"` be a match? in your code it will; in the original code, it won't

Comment: @MarcGravell You are right. To be honest, I didn't look too much OP's code becuase he wants to get _If the string is "cat:fox" method should returns true. If the string is "dog:fox" method should returns true._

Answer (score 2):

In most circumstances, the code you post is fine. If you need to minimize allocations (because it is a tight loop), so don't want to `Split`, you can use something like:

```
public static bool ContainsToken(string value, string token, char delimiter = ';')
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) return false;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return false;

    int lastIndex = -1, idx, endIndex = value.Length - token.Length, tokenLength = token.Length;
    while ((idx = value.IndexOf(token, lastIndex + 1)) > lastIndex)
    {
        lastIndex = idx;
        if ((idx == 0 || (value[idx - 1] == delimiter))
            && (idx == endIndex || (value[idx + tokenLength] == delimiter)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

then something like:

```
static bool ContainsAnyOf(string value, string values)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < strArr.Length; i++)
    {
        if(ContainsToken(values, value, ':')) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
bool contains = strArr.Any(pattern => str.Contains(pattern));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, you don't have to split the original string and create a double loop:

```
foreach(string s in array)
    if(word.Contains(s))
        return true;
return false;
```

In a method:

```
public bool ContainsItem(string word, string[] array)
{
    foreach(string s in array)
        if(word.Contains(s))
            return true;                
    return false;
}

//Usage:
var result = ContainsItem(str, strArr);
```

Or you can use the `Enumerable Any()` method:

```
var result = strArr.Any(s => str.Contains(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a List instead of an Array:

```
string str = "cat:fox";
List<String> animallist = new List<String>();

animallist.add("cat");
animallist.add("dog");

//Now you can check like

if(animallist.Contains("cat")){

   //do something

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is correct!

---

Though if you a have very large string separated by `:` and you want to perform look up operations quite frequently you can use [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since it's `Contains` method is O(1) and so is very fast!

```
var dictionary=str.Split(new char[]{':'})
                  .ToDictionary(x=>x,x=>"");
bool contains=strArr.Any(x=>dictionary.ContainsKey(x));//fast ops
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "cat:fox";
var strArr = new[] { "cat", "dog" };

var result = strArr.ToList().Where(str.Contains);
```

First element of `result` will contain 'cat'